# String to display number currency in Android

Tags: android

I have a string

```
String retail = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("retail"));
```

The date is being passed as "99999", I need it to print out as "999.99", how can I do this?

Comment: Divide by 100? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried
Double retD = Double.parseDouble(retail);
       NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
       String retS = format.format(retD);
       Log.v("Retail", retS.toString());
But it comes out as $509,000.00 should be $5.09.

Comment: why you store price in `String` without decimal mark? Store value in `Float` would be better..

Answer (score 0):

If you always have to add the "." 2 character before the end, this should work:

```
retail = retail.substring(0, retail.length()-2) + "." + retail.substring(retail.length()-2,retail.length());
```

This will add a dot two character before the end of the String, as you need.

Comment: This one is the simplest solution, probably not elegant but clear and simple.